# Integrated workspace Tabular Model link to Power BI desktop?

Tags: powerbi, ssas, ssas-tabular

I've created an integrated workspace SSAS tabular model in VS2019 which sits on my local machine.  Basically I've not created a explicit analysis service instance of this on a server.  What I would like to do is rather than test this on a local version of excel, I would like to test this on an instance of PowerBI Desktop on my machine.

Is it possible to do this?  If so, how would I add this as a data source into PowerBI?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workspace server port number will change every time you start Visual Studio. But you can connect Power BI Desktop by looking at the Workspace Server property in the Properties pane in Visual Studio.

[image: Workspace Server in Properties pane]
*From this [blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/analysisservices/introducing-integrated-workspace-mode-for-sql-server-data-tools-for-analysis-services-tabular-projects-ssdt-tabular?)*